# Powershell go dynamically go down 2 path

Tags: powershell, directory, filepath

```
 Copy-Item -Path \\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\20200120\FWES_0D526B00D2\files\*.txt
```

I am trying to copy text files from this path, however FWES_0D526B00D2 directory name changes every day. ex.FWES_0D526B00D5, FWES_0D526B00D6, FWES_0D526B04Z4 etc.... Is there any ways to dynamically choose this path to pull files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one directory in 20200120 with FWES... at any given time, you should be able to use `Copy-Item -Path "\\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\20200120\FWES*\files\*.txt"`
If the FWES directories are being added and the old ones still exist, this obviously won't work.

Another option would be to find the newest FWES directory based on directory creationtime attribute and from there you'll get the full path.

It looks like my first solution doesn't work with UNC paths. Try this:

```
    $path = (Get-Item -Path "\\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\20200120\FWES*").FullName
    $path += "\files\*.txt"
    Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination ""
```

Comment: Yes, in 20200120 there is only one folder, but if I do FWES* instead of adding a full name, code gets ignored......

Comment: @ted, I had tested it with regular path and it worked but not with UNC path. I just tested it with UNC path and as you said it failed. I edited my answer and added a new solution that worked with UNC path.